# Where is linux terminal's session history stored?

Tags: linux, terminal

I wanted to get the location of the session command history in linux terminal. I am not looking for .bash_history as it is updated only when a session is closed. I want the commands run in a session without actually closing the session.

Basically, I want to get those commands programmatically and work over them. Even if some tool is available which can be invoked programmatically to do so, I can work with it.

Comment: `shopt -s histappend; export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` - add these to your `~/.bashrc`, and every single command from any session gets written to `~/.bash_history` ... also saves you from sessions overwriting each others history. That said: this is not a programming question; voted to close.

Comment: Ignore the bit about the close vote - doesn't apply anymore after your question was migrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`, and every single command from any session gets written to `~/.bash_history`.

```
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

... also saves you from sessions overwriting each others history.

Answer (score 2):

For Bash specifically, you should be able to use [the `fc` and `history` builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html) to access the history list for the current shell and / or manipulate the history file. Note well that those are not at all the same thing, not least because you can have multiple concurrent sessions and multiple shells in a session, but each user has only one history file.  Of course, which specific `fc` or `history` command you want depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: This worked but not exactly what I wanted, I couldn't invoke these commands programmatically (with execv or similar ) as they are built-in bash commands.